# Fail to open vscode in WSL bash on ubuntu using cmd code

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

When I tried to open vscode in WSL bash on Ubuntu 20.04 using command `code .`, it failed and the following message was logged:

```
/mnt/c/Users/john/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl-0.50.1/scripts/wslCode.sh: 57: /home/john/.vscode-server/bin/d2e414d9e4239a252d1ab117bd7067f125afd80a/bin/code: not found
```

I would like to ask how to fix this problem? Thx a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. Even though I think that you've already know it.

You need to delete the folder `/home/john/.vscode-server/` with `sudo rm -rf /home/john/.vscode-server`.

Then, you just run `code .` or try to open any project that you want it.

Then a script will load and will install a new `.vscode-server` in your machine with the right files.