# WSL vscode command returning error "not found"

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have this message whenever I try to type `code .`

[image: Screen capture containing an output obtained probably at a Unix-based WSL 2 terminal running on Windows. The output text is quoted exactly in the rest of the question for accessibility.]

```bash
/mnt/c/Users/jerom/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl-0.63.13/scripts/wslCode.sh: 69: /home/jerome/.vscode-server-server/bin/f80445acd5a3dadef24aa209168452a3d97cc326/bin/code: not found
```

Can someone help me please?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you taken a look at this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64499108/fail-to-open-vscode-in-wsl-bash-on-ubuntu-using-cmd-code

Answer (score 32):

I just now had the same issue on WSL2 Kali. I tried everything given here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/2962.

My problem was VS Code was not on Kali's path. Here's how I fixed it :)

```bash
echo $PATH
# Confirm PATH is missing this: 
/mnt/c/Users/wcd/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin/

# Confirm VS Code's location then export:
export PATH=$PATH:"/mnt/c/Users/wcd/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin/" 
# It's temporarily added to path...
echo $PATH
# This should now trigger VS Code Server install,
# then open ~/ in VS Code. 
code .

# If above works, make it permanent:
echo 'export PATH=$PATH:"/mnt/c/Users/wcd/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin/"' >> ~/.bashrc

# Restart shell + test
exec "$SHELL"
code .
```

Comment: This is the ONE.

Comment: As someone else pointed out: your windows PATH to the bin might not be under `AppData/Local/Programs`

Answer (score 21):

Fixed it

- Open VS Code on Windows
- Open Extensions and then search on WSL

It should say the extension needs to be reloaded - go ahead and reload it

- Open WSL and type code

This should force another upgrade of code and this time it should launch.

Comment: Tried everything here, this is what worked

Comment: Make sure to close the terminal and reopen again before retrying

Answer (score 12):

I solved this problem by opening windows powershell in admin mode and typing the following command:

```
wsl --update
```

Then I typed this command to force restart the WSL and all done

```
wsl --shutdown
```

Comment: This solved the problem on win11, not win10

Answer (score 9):

This also happens if you disable the Windows PATH on WSL. I had my VS Code working fine, then when I disable the windows PATH (by editing/creating the `/etc/wsl.conf` file and inserting the `[interop] appendWindowsPath = false` parameter) the `code` command stopped working.

The ek1n8 solution solves my problem, addind the export manually to the WSL Path:

```
export PATH=$PATH:"/mnt/c/Users/%USERNAME%/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin"
```

Comment: Thank you!!!! Works for me! appendWindowsPath = true

Comment: I completely forgot I removed this and was wondering why everyone else seemed to have "code" already in there "PATH". 
Thanks

Comment: My VS Code was installed under `C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin`

Answer (score 5):

I have same issue when I trying export my old wsl and move whole project to nvme ssd using new distro.

I able to run the `code .` on **root** , but when i switch to my name then it doesn't work, I guess is WSL PATH problem.

I not really familiar to the linux, the below image may easier for you to understand what i am saying.

[image]

When i use `echo $PATH` on wsl to compare root and my account, and i notice that VS code directory only found on root instead of my account.

So i use `export PATH=$PATH:"/mnt/c/Users/ricso/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin"` to add the VS Code path to my account* and `code .` is working once i export this.

But the `code .` will not be able to run again if you restart the wsl, so we need to put in to bashrc.

But when i try to update my account's* PATH using
`echo "PATH=$PATH:/mnt/c/Users/ricso/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft\ VS\ Code/bin" >> ~/.bashrc` and restart the wsl to login my account, i notice an error msg popup when run the `code .`

> cannot create /tmp/remote-wsl-loc.txt: Permission denied

And i found this.
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/5389

Seem they only giving the workaround for now and hopefully can fix it soon.

*disclaimer above: this code need to run under your account instead of root

**For editing bashrc, instead of using echo and >> write to the file, you also can use `code ~/.bashrc` to update/edit, when you have the vscode access on wsl.

Answer (score 3):

For me adding the binary to Path was enough:

```
export PATH=$PATH:"/mnt/c/Users/%USERNAME%/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try these 5 simple steps:

1. Stop WSL: On the PowerShell type `wsl --shutdown`
2. Uninstall VS Code WSL extension
3. Install VS Code WSL extension again
4. Start WSL with the user you like to try `code` command, typing on PowerShell the following command `wsl ~ -u MyUser`
5. Navigate to your app directory and type `code .` on the batch terminal or specify the whole path `code ./myapps/hello-world-app`

Answer (score 0):

For me it was wsl using the wrong container:

```
 wsl --list -v
  NAME                   STATE           VERSION
* docker-desktop-data    Stopped         2
  Ubuntu                 Running         2
```

I did `wsl  -s  ubuntu`

```
 wsl --list -v
  NAME                   STATE           VERSION
* Ubuntu                 Running         2
  docker-desktop-data    Stopped         2
```

and it solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this issue after setting up WSL and vscode on a new computer.

The solution that worked for me was to **sign out of windows**. Once I logged back in the PATH env variable seemed correct and launching vscode from WSL worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Go to VS code on Windows, extensions -> WSL, install it.
Then restart the WSL subsystem and will work.

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution.

On my machine, Visual Studio Code had been installed by an Admin for all users, and I found that not only was `code .` not available within my WSL environment, but commands like `Dev Container: Reopen in Container` failed to work as well.

Installing a private copy of Visual Studio Code (which is the normal default), made everything work.

```bash
$ which code
/mnt/c/Users/bearps/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin/code
```

To check your situation, open a PowerShell prompt and run

```
PS> get-command code
CommandType     Name        Version    Source
-----------     ----        -------    ------
Application     code.cmd    0.0.0.0    C:\Users\bearps\AppData\Local\Programs\Microso...
```

If the location shown is under `C:\Program Files` or `C:\Program Files (x86)` try switching to a local install.

Answer (score 0):

what worked for me was :

```
wsl --shutdown
```

and then

```
wsl --restart
```

Answer (score 0):

you just need to add .bashrc file with:
export PATH=$PATH:"/mnt/c/Users//AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin"

Answer (score 0):

For who are using Insiders version (and have uninstalled stable version), you should use command `code-insiders .` instead `code .`

If you wish to use just `code .`, go to the win folder:
`\Users\:userprofile\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code Insiders\bin`

and clone the file `code-insiders`, renaiming to `code`

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was:

1. Enter Wsl and do:

> 

```
rm -rf ~/.vscode-server/data
```

2. Then, open Task Manager and end all VS Code related tasks.
3. Open VS Code :)

Answer (score 0):

Tried a bunch of stuff. I believe I lost myself trying to fix some packages. I tried

```
rm -rf ~/.vscode-server/
wsl --shutdown
```

Reinstalling my WSL plugin on VSCode. What really made it to get back working for me was

```
wsl --update
```

In my case, the WSL connection was effective, but no code command inside bash. The error was

```
run-detectors: unable to find an interpreter for /mnt/c/Users/myuser/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/Code.exe
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I was using the Mamba package manager, and VSCode was in the path, but it didn't work.  After I uninstalled mamba, it worked. I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

**Simply**: It's the same command `code .` from your desired directory.

Note: You must need to install `wsl` extension in your **VS Code**